# Tests fail during TFS build while using the ncrypted web.config file

Tags: encryption, tfs, web-config

I am encrypting my web.config [custom sections and connection strings] using aspnet_regiis utility. I have unit tests which use the data in the encrypted sections. These tests fail when run in a TFS build [as the keys do not exist on TFS server]. 
What is the best way to install the key on TFS server?

Comment: Are you able to run test locally? Could you share the detailed log?

Comment: I am able to successfully run the tests locally as I have the key installed, however I am trying to find a best approach to install the key on server.

Comment: Which key do you install? Is it machine key? How do you install the key on your local machine? Do you use hosted build agent or on-premise build agent?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the steps in this article to export and import the Key: [Importing and Exporting Protected Configuration RSA Key Containers](http://Importing%20and%20Exporting%20Protected%20Configuration%20RSA%20Key%20Containers) and make sure the key is installed on the server which run the build.